# Cloned a public repo, pushed back. Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, github, repository

Just cloned a `public` repo that belongs to the `company` on github where I am an `admin`. Made few changes and pushing it back.

Firsly, it asks me the `username / password` pair, and I put my own username and password, and it told me:

```
Username for 'github.com': 
Password for 'github.com': 
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing https://github.com/KablamoAU/SenchaXCodeBuild.git/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

I solved it by adding `ssh` to the URL

Than it bugs me out with:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

However I can commit to all the `private` repos in this organisation and can create other repos as well.

So my question is:

1. Why doesn't github allow me to commit to `master` of the cloned repo, but it is a trivial question
2. Should I add key to the organization in order to push to the `public` repo? Or what solution would you provide

PS. Never thought that such a simple issue might take so long time to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you have 
[added key](http://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys)
from this file to GitHub

```
~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

then make sure you are cloning with URL similar to this

```
git clone git@github.com:antirez/redis.git
```

yet another option is to contact them directly if you have not already. I have emailed them several times, with pleasant experience.

```
support@github.com
```

Also perhaps this page can help

[Error: Permission denied (publickey)](http://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey)